# video module, MIME problem

Tags: files

I have installed the video module of the Drupal 7 distribution. I have added the "video" field to my content type. When I upload the mp4 format of the video, I get the following message:

> No video with support format and MIME type found.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the player set to play files of that type might help. If not, installing one of the transcoders like ffmpeg or Zencoder will fix it. If that's not practical, you can use other modules besides Video, and create your own video field, for example the jPlayer module (which takes any m4v videos, a variation on mp4)